# In admin I see "App_name object" but not actual object name

Tags: django

So, I learning django by this http://mherman.org/blog/2012/12/30/django-basics/ tutorial and I have one problem.

I added couple books to database but in admin site I see only "App_name object". In my case I see only list of words "Books object", "Books object", "Books object" when actually I should see "War and Peace", "Brave New World", "To Kill a Mockingbird".

So, do you know what's wrong with my app?

Thank you ;)

edited: add my models.py code

```
from django.db import models

class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    read = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title + " / " + self.author + " / " + self.read
```

I found answer:

> Django 1.5 has experimental support for Python 3, but the Django 1.5
>   tutorial is written for Python 2.X:
>
> This tutorial is written for Django 1.5 and Python 2.x. If the Django
>   version doesn’t match, you can refer to the tutorial for your version
>   of Django or update Django to the newest version. If you are using
>   Python 3.x, be aware that your code may need to differ from what is in
>   the tutorial and you should continue using the tutorial only if you
>   know what you are doing with Python 3.x.
>
> In Python 3, you should define a **str** method instead of a
>   **unicode** method. There is a decorator python_2_unicode_compatible which helps you to write code which works in Python 2 and 3.
>
> @python_2_unicode_compatible class Poll(models.Model):
>       question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
>       pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
>
> ```
> def __str__(self):
>     return self.question For more information see the section str and unicode methods in the Porting to Python 3 docs.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined (or did it incorrectly) `__unicode__()` method of your `Books` model:

> 5. Next, open up your models.py file and add these two lines of code-
>
> ```
>  def __unicode__(self):
>      return self.title + " / " + self.author + " / " + self.read
> ```

FYI, quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__):

> The `__unicode__()` method is called whenever you call unicode() on an
>   object. Django uses `unicode(obj)` (or the related function, `str(obj)`)
>   in a number of places. **Most notably, to display an object in the
>   Django admin site** and as the value inserted into a template when it
>   displays an object. Thus, you should always return a nice,
>   human-readable representation of the model from the `__unicode__()`
>   method.

Comment: @princas11 could you show your `models.py`? (include it into the question)

Comment: I added my models.py to the first post.

Comment: could be an issue with stale pyc files. Remove the pyc files and try again.